# How to use psutil module on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, cpu-usage, psutil

I am trying to get cpu temperature using psutil module. I installed it using

```
pip install psutil
```

It installed perfectly fine. However, when I try to import it I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
import psutil
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 147, 
in <module>
from . import _pswindows as _psplatform
File "C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 35, in 
<module>
from ._psutil_windows import ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil._psutil_windows'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by downgrading my psutil from version **5.7.0** to **4.1.0** using the following command:

```
pip install psutil==4.1.0
```

I'm not sure what the actual reason for this error is. Perhaps an incompatibility with your python version? In my case, I was using Python 3.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `psutil` manually by using the prebuilt wheel from Gohlke's collection
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil)

To install manually (from cmd or Powershell) use:

```bash
pip install C:\Users\me\Downloads\psutil‑5.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl
```